# EXC_BREAKPOINT when starting iPhone app

Tags: iphone, crash, dyld

A user of our app sent me the following crash log (already symbolicated):

```
Incident Identifier: 59D4D5E7-570A-4047-A679-3016B2A226C4
CrashReporter Key:   d8284d671ee22ad17511360ce73409ebfa8b84bb
Process:         .... [63]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/....
Identifier:      ...
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-03-08 17:00:15.437 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 2.2.1 (5H11a)
Report Version:  103

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                 0x2fe01060 dyld_fatal_error + 0
1   dyld                 0x2fe088d4 dyld::_main(mach_header
const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**)
+ 3064
2   dyld                 0x2fe0196c
dyldbootstrap::start(mach_header const*, int, char const**, long) +
884
3   dyld                 0x2fe01048 _dyld_start + 32

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
   r0: 0x2fe23ca0    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x2fe23ca0      r3:
0x00000000
   r4: 0x2ffff4e0    r5: 0x2ffff4bc      r6: 0x2fe005c0      r7:
0x2ffffb00
   r8: 0x00000004    r9: 0x2fe57cf0     r10: 0x2fe236c8     r11:
0x00000009
   ip: 0x0000018d    sp: 0x2ffff5b8      lr: 0x2fe088dc      pc:
0x2fe01060
 cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe22fff  dyld ??? (???)
<f6a50d5f57a676b54276d0ecef46d5f0> /usr/lib/dyld
```

My app uses OpenFeint and PinchMedia analytics. For PinchMedia, I'm linking using their provided .a file, and for OpenFeint, I'm compiling their code (as per their guidelines).
The frameworks / libs I'm linking are:

- UIKit.framework (**Weak**)
- MapKit.framework (**Weak**)
- Foundation.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- OpenAL.framework
- AudioToolbox.framework
- libsqlite3
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- PinchMedia analytics
- Security.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- CFNetwork.framework

My base SDK is iPhone 3.0, and my Base OS Deployment Target is 2.2.1.

There are two things I find weird:

1. The app crashes even before the main method is invoked.
2. The crash log looks exactly like the one posted here: [Objective-C iPhone App EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368689/objective-c-iphone-app-exc-breakpoint-sigtrap)

The user that sent me this crash is using a 2nd gen iPod Touch with OS 2.2.1. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, but based on the comments in iTunes, it seems that more people is having the same issue.

Comment: We can't tell you much because we don't know what the symbols are in the crash report. Follow [these instructions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html) to convert the crash report into a human readable format: With out symbolication (gods what a word) the crash report is just gibberish.

Comment: The report IS symbolicated. Without symbolication the first line says `0x2fe01060 0x2fe00000 + 4192` instead of `0x2fe01060 dyld_fatal_error + 0`

Comment: usually gives you a little more detail.

Comment: The report is symbolicated, I'm having the *exact* same problem with a Universal app :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. Solution: [Weak link UIKit.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618889/universal-iphone-ipad-application-debug-compilation-error-for-iphone-testing/2622027#2622027)