# Weird EXC_Crash (SIGKILL) error report

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, crash, sigkill

When I start my app on device, the screen goes black and the app crashes. But the screen remains black rather than typical crash where you are brought back to springboard. Here's my crash error:

```
Incident Identifier: 28A191D0-5795-4EEA-81EB-5C12628A47B0
CrashReporter Key:   9185dbd80ba3cc9fed14413529e4c277f99bca98
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         Dixie Mat Tracker [11536]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A170FE48-8FCE-4C47-B69C-0F048C50281C/Dixie Mat Tracker.app/Dixie Mat Tracker
Identifier:      Dixie Mat Tracker
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-07-06 17:04:21.131 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x2fe0124a dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*) + 446
1   dyld                            0x2fe01058 _dyld_start + 48

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000009      r2: 0x00000009      r3: 0x00026000
    r4: 0x0002601c    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000005      r7: 0x2fe24a38
    r8: 0x2fe4b18c    r9: 0x2fe72964     r10: 0x2fe254f4     r11: 0x00025000
    ip: 0x2fe72984    sp: 0x2fe249f0      lr: 0x2fe249cc      pc: 0x2fe2624a
  cpsr: 0x60000030

Binary Images:
0x2fe25000 - 0x2fe4afff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457927/exc-breakpoint-when-starting-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when upgrading to the LLVM compiler in Xcode 4.2. The offending configuration option was in "Other Linker Flags". I basically removed everything that was in there which was:

```
-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib -all_load
```

Once I deleted those options, I was able to run the application on the simulator again, without the `dyldbootstrap::start` crash.