# Check for availability of blocks at runtime on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, backwards-compatibility, objective-c-blocks

I need to test for the availability of blocks at runtime, so I can handle backwards compatibility with iOS 3. Any tips?

edit:
So far I'm doing `if (!NSClassFromString(@"NSBlockOperation")) {...}`
Seems to be working...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will also need to make sure to weak link the `libSystem.B.dylib`, set your base SDK to 4.0 and deployment target to 3.1.3, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313786/ios-4-app-crashes-at-startup-on-ios-3-1-3-symbol-not-found-nsconcretestackblo).

A good overview on how to deal with iOS versioning issues can also be found in this this Cocoa with Love article: [Tips & Tricks for conditional iOS3, iOS3.2 and iOS4 code](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html)

Comment: I assume weakly linking libSystem.B.dylib lets me use NSBlockOperation instead of doing NSClassFromString every time. Oh for it to be a year from now, when I'll safely be able to drop support for iOS 3.

Comment: @Kenny I believe so. Also check out the Tips & Tricks link. It has a few different approaches to having various versions of SDK coexist within your app.