# iOS: Game center crash on simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gamekit, game-center

This is driving me crazy, I just can't find out the problem:
I have a crash on game center on simulator, in the device it works perfect.
It crashes when I call the following code:

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
        NSLog(@"An error occured authenticating the local game center player");
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);      
    }
}];
```

I've tried setting both deployment target and base sdk to 4.3 with no luck.
I've tried doing the call from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and also doing it later after the player clicks on the "play" button in the main screen. Both cases the same result.

Also, I get no stack trace; it looks like this:

```
0 objc_msgSend
1 < ???? >
```

I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: if you get a trace like that, it can be from another tread, you can look through those threads too, also make sure that you are using a simulator version that supports blocks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this, i'm facing this problem right now

Comment: @possan: yes, look at my own answer!

Comment: Ah, ok, well that didnt solve it for me but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that in '`Other Linker Flags`' option in xcode I had `-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` changing this to `-weak-lSystem` fixes the problem

I found other person with the same problem in a comment in this question: [iOS 4 app crashes at startup on iOS 3.1.3: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteStackBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313786/ios-4-app-crashes-at-startup-on-ios-3-1-3-symbol-not-found-nsconcretestackblo)