# dyld: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteGlobalBlock after updating to OSX 10.8

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I just updated to Mac OSX10.8 and I'm trying to compile a Mac app that ran perfectly when using 10.7 + Xcode 4.5. Now I get this error:

dyld: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteGlobalBlock

Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices

I've looked everywhere and things seem to be ok. The deployment target for the app is 10.6 which already supports blocks. Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Yes, definitely did that... I even manually removed all derived data :(

Comment: Any other error info from the compiler?

Comment: Unfortunately not... this is the full output:  dyld: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteGlobalBlock
  Referenced from: /Users/quique/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-name-fauddduqhavbyhgmmihrbdxrpjic/Build/Products/Debug/app-name.app/Contents/MacOS/app-name
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
 in /Users/quique/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-name-fauddduqhavbyhgmmihrbdxrpjic/Build/Products/Debug/app-name.app/Contents/MacOS/app-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my project was trying to use an old version of the CoreServices framework which was causing this issue. I re-added all the frameworks that my project was using and the problem was gone :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 on your question... Not sure if that would help finding the problem with OS X, but there is a similar error that happens with iPhone apps, with a solution in the link below. Another reason I am providing this link is that googling this error for the iPhone got me to this page. 
[iOS 4 app crashes at startup on iOS 3.1.3: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteStackBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313786/ios-4-app-crashes-at-startup-on-ios-3-1-3-symbol-not-found-nsconcretestackbl)